# How can I remove a role from a user, knowing only his id?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

How can I remove a role from a user, knowing only his id?
I'm currently using this code:

```
if self.collection.find_one({"name": name, "lname": lname, "role": role.id})['user'] != None:
    id = self.collection.find_one({"name": name, "lname": lname, "role": role.id})['user']
    await self.client.get_user(id).remove_roles(role)
self.collection.remove({"name": name, "lname": lname, "role": role.id})
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

pls help

Comment: whatever is being returned from mongo doesn't have a valid `user` id, perhaps print out what's returned from mongo, it's likely just as a string or something. Also, `client.get_user` will return a `User` object, you'll need to use `Guild.get_member(id)` to add roles

Comment: Is this in a command or an event? If so, you can use  `ctx.guild` to get the guild, and then what pjones said use `guild.get_member(id)` to get the member, and then remove a role from him using the `remove_roles` method found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.remove_roles)

Comment: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_member'